# Not able to host node js app in Azure web app

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a app written in node js and angular js. The folder structure looks like this:[image]

When I run it on local by doing nmp install and then ng server, it workes as expected. However, when I try to deploy it in Azure web app, either the zipdeploy fails or if I connect via GitHub connector, the site comes out to be broken after the deployment.

I looked up contents available over the internet. It seems like I need app.js or server.js for deplyoing my app in Azure. My question is, how do I generate it? and do I deploy the whole folder or only the contents of "dist" folder (created after ng build).

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are deploying all the packages.

Be sure the you are getting a production build:

```
ng build --prod
```

If you are using VS Code read this:

https://dzone.com/articles/deploy-an-angular-app-from-visual-studio-code-to-a-1